# Are all operators in Quantum Mechanics both Hermitian and Unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurements

I am trying to understand the basics of quantum mechanics and I am having some issues in understanding the main mathematical properties of quantum operators. In particular, it's clear to me that:

- Quantum operators must be Hermitian to guarantee:

  - real eigenvalues, that can be measured
  - an orthogonal basis, so that after each measure the state of the system collapses onto a precise base-state
- Unitary operators are needed because they preserve norms: if we apply a non unitary operator to a system, its total probability would not be preserved.

It's clear to me that the Hamiltonian is both a hermitian and unitary operator.

In any book I have read, I have only found statements such as "operators in quantum mechanics must be hermitian" or "time evolution is unitary", but I've never found a statement such as "operators must be both hermitian and unitary": why is that? Shouldn't all operators be both, to guarantee measurability and conservation of norm?

Comment: "It's clear that the Hamiltonian is both hermitian and unitary." No. This is not true, so how it could be clear?

Comment: The Hamiltonian is certainly not unitary, although *its exponential* $e^{-it\hat H/\hbar}$ is unitary if $H$ is Hermitian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hamiltonian is *not* (typically) unitary. In order for an operator to be unitary, its spectrum must lie on the unit circle; if it is Hermitian, its spectrum must be real. Putting those things together, an operator which is both unitary and Hermitian must have a spectrum which is a subset of $\{-1,1\}$, which is obviously not true of a generic Hamiltonian.

The time-evolution operator $U_t$ *is* unitary, and at least for time-independent Hamiltonians is given by $U_t = \exp[-it H/\hbar]$.  More generally, a self-adjoint operator $A$ corresponds to a family of unitary operators $U(\lambda) = \exp[-i\lambda A]$ (maybe with some constants thrown in there for dimensional reasons) via the [Stone theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups); the interpretation of this correspondence is that the observable $A$ *generates* the family of symmetry transformations $\exp[-i\lambda A]$, which is more or less the Hamiltonian equivalent of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

---

*Observables* in quantum mechanics are represented by Hermitian operators (or rather, self-adjoint operators, though the distinction is more technical than the level of this question), which are not generally unitary.  *Symmetry transformations* in quantum mechanics are represented by unitary (or antiunitary) operators, which are not generally Hermitian/self-adjoint. Some operators - such as the ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ which you will meet when you study the quantum harmonic oscillator - are neither; other operators such as the spatial inversion operator and (obviously) the identity operator are both.

Comment: Thank you, that was insightful. It makes sense to me that the ladder operators, that can be seen as creation/annihilitation, are not unitary: they literally create or destroying a particle, and changing the existence-state of a system is just what "changing the total probability" means. Right?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no "the Hamiltonian" as this language implies an existing notion of a Hamiltonian or the existence of a unique object called "Hamiltonian". Neither of which is true.
2. A Hamiltonian in general is not unitary.
3. Operators in general can be Hermitian, unitary, both, or neither. Operators of physical importance in Quantum Mechanics are typically either Hermitian or unitary for the reasons you mention in your post. In particular, observables are usually described using Hermitian $\text{operators}.$ And, transformations are described using unitary operators.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are completely correct, but since you stated so confidently that the Hamiltonian is both unitary and Hermitian I just wanted to add that it is very easy to come up with an example Hamiltonian that we can prove is not unitary.

In particular, consider the Hamiltonian for a free particle:
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2
$$
**If** $\hat{H}$ were unitary, then it would be the case that $\hat{H}^\dagger \hat{H} = \hat{H}^2 = 1$. (The second equality comes about because the Hamiltonian **is** Hermitian, so $\hat{H}^\dagger = \hat{H}$). Then, for **any** wavefunction $\psi(x)$, we should be able to prove that $\hat{H}^\dagger \hat{H} \psi = \hat{H}^2 \psi = \psi$.

We can disprove this proposition with a single counterexample. Let's take $\psi=e^{i p x / \hbar}$. Then
$$
\hat{H}^2 \psi = \frac{\hbar^4}{4m^2} \nabla^4 e^{i p x / \hbar} = \frac{p^4}{4 m^2} e^{i p x / \hbar} \neq e^{i p x / \hbar}
$$
Therefore, $\hat{H}$ is not unitary.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first statement about the relation between hermiticity of an operator and its spectrum. Hermiticity of an operator is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition for its eigenvalues to be real. Non-hermitian Hamiltonians can also have real spectra, given they are symmetric under space-time reflections. For example, the energy levels of

$$H = p^2+ix^3$$

are real and positive [1]. Though from personal experience on conferences, "non-hermitian quantum mechanics" is still a lively (and sometimes hotly) debated research field.

[1] Bender, C. M. Making sense of non-Hermitian Hamiltonians. Reports on Progress in Physics 70, 947 (2007).